# is it possible to change response on proxy level using varnish?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, varnish

For example we have setup like this:

```
user -> api gateway -> (specific endpoint) varnish -> backend service
```

If backend returns response `500 {"message":"error"}` I want to patch this response and return `200 "[]"` instead.

Is it possible to do something like this using varnish or some other proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to intercept backend errors, and convert them into regular responses.

A very simplistic example is the following:

```
sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "application/json";
    set beresp.status = 200;
    set beresp.body = "[]";
    return(deliver);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if(beresp.status == 500) {
        return(error(200,"OK"));
    }
}
```

Whenever your backend would fail, and return an `HTTP/503` error, we will send a `HTTP/200` response with `[]` output.

This output template for backend errors is also triggered when the backend does reply, but with a `HTTP/500` error.

In real world scenarios, I would a some conditional logic in `vcl_backend_error` to only return  the *JSON output template* when specific criteria are matched. For example: a certain URL pattern was matched.

I would advise the same in `vcl_backend_response`: maybe you don't want to convert all `HTTP/500` errors into regular `HTTP/200` responses. Maybe you also want to add conditional logic.